# AWS S3 Errors when trying to authenticate with rails.application.credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml

I've set up an S3 bucket and an using it in my Rails development environment to store my active storage files.

It works fine when I have the following in my storage.yml file:

```
aws:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: myaccesskeyid
  secret_access_key: mysecretaccesskey
  region: eu-west-2
  bucket: bucketname
```

But when I try to set the access_key_id and secret_access_key via my credentials.yml using `EDITOR="mate --wait" bin/rails credentials:edit`, I get the following error:

```
Aws::S3::Errors::Forbidden in Pages#home

Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 311ms (ActiveRecord: 13.6ms)

ActionView::Template::Error ():
    12:     <% @items.each do |item| %>
    13:         <%= link_to item, class: 'col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 home_items__item' do %>
    14:             <div class="item-preview">
    15:                 <%= image_tag(item.feature_thumb, class:"img-fluid")%>
    16:                 <div class="item-preview__title">
    17:                     <%= item.title %>
    18:                 </div>

app/models/item.rb:45:in `feature_thumb'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:15:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_pages_home_html_erb__4520288450801053047_70162336881260'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:13:in `block in _app_views_pages_home_html_erb__4520288450801053047_70162336881260'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__4520288450801053047_70162336881260'
Started PUT "/__web_console/repl_sessions/bfa895913555c494e18f3b259169a041" for ::1 at 2019-08-14 20:39:17 +0100

NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

My credentials.yml looks like this:

```
aws:
  access_key_id: myaccesskeyid
  secret_access_key: mysecretaccesskey
```

My Amended storage.yml looks like this:

```
aws:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id]
  secret_access_key: Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key]
  region: eu-west-2
  bucket: bucketname
```

and calling those credentials from the console on the errored browser window returns the correct credentials:

```
> Rails.application.credentials.aws[:access_key_id]
> "myaccesskeyid"
>  Rails.application.credentials.aws[:secret_access_key]
> "mysecretaccesskey"
```

Any ideas about what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like a AWS bucket issue. I'll paste the stack trace you've provided and highlight the key point:

app/models/item.rb:45:in `feature_thumb' <----------------This is the key line
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:15:in`block (2 levels) in _app_views_pages_home_html_erb__4520288450801053047_70162336881260'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:13:in `block in _app_views_pages_home_html_erb__4520288450801053047_70162336881260'
app/views/pages/home.html.erb:12:in`_app_views_pages_home_html_erb__4520288450801053047_70162336881260'
Started PUT "/__web_console/repl_sessions/bfa895913555c494e18f3b259169a041" for ::1 at 2019-08-14 20:39:17 +0100

**NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass**  <----- this the key line.

This means that you are using the `map` method somewhere in your `feature_thumb` method. Except that the object you are calling it on is `nil`. You will need to make sure that the map method is called only if the object is not nil.